# I want fetch substring from in oracle table between last '/' and before '.' from last in images table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I want to fetch substring from string in column  between last '/' and last '.' .

Here is sample date for  IMAGE_PATH column name:

```
 sph/images/30_Fairhall_Court.jpeg
 sph/images/9_Pennethorne_House.jpeg
 rbkc/images/TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT.jpeg
 haringey/images/399932thumb.jpg
 urbanchoice/images/18190862.jpg
 wandle/images/f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc.png
 housingmoves/images/No14_Asterid Heights_DS37620.jpg
 wandle/images/f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc.png
```

So the required output is like

```
 30_Fairhall_Court
 9_Pennethorne_House
 TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT
 399932thumb
 18190862
 f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc
 No14_Asterid Heights_DS37620
 f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc
```

Please suggest how to fetch. I need to update another blank column in table with  this value.   The table has around 10 lacks records.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works with the sample data you provided:

```
select regexp_substr(image_path
            , '(/)([a-z0-9_ \-]+)(\.)([a-z]+)$'
            , 1
            , 1
            , 'i'
            , 2) 
from t23
/
```

We have to include all the optional parameters after `pattern` so we can use the `subexpr` parameter to select just the filename element.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06303).

---

As far as the updating goes, a million row table isn't that big.  Given that you have to update all the rows there's not much you can do to tune it.  Just issue the UPDATE statement and let it rip.

---

> "its not working"

Hmmm, here's [a SQL Fiddle which proves it does work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0e22/2).  You've probably introduced a typo.

> "The regexp looks unnecessary complex. Why not simply"

Perhaps it is too complicated.  However your simplified version doesn't produce the correct result if there's more than one dot in the IMAGE_PATH.  If that's never going to happen then your solution works just fine.

Comment: The regexp looks unnecessary complex. Why not simply: `([^/]+)\..+$`

Comment: @AnujKumarKushwaha -  "It's not working" isn't very informative.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to use functions substr() and [instr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) with negative third parameter:

```
select image_path, 
    substr(image_path, 
           instr(image_path, '/', -1) + 1, 
           instr(image_path, '.', -1)-instr(image_path, '/', -1) - 1) img
  from test
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4c29a/1)

Results:

```
IMAGE_PATH                                                IMG
--------------------------------------------------------  -------------------------------------
sph/images/30_Fairhall_Court.jpeg                         30_Fairhall_Court
sph/images/9_Pennethorne_House.jpeg                       9_Pennethorne_House
rbkc/images/TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT.jpeg                       TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT
haringey/images/399932thumb.jpg                           399932thumb
urbanchoice/images/18190862.jpg                           18190862
wandle/images/f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc.png    f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc
housingmoves/images/No14_Asterid Heights_DS37620.jpg      No14_Asterid Heights_DS37620
wandle/ima.ges/f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc.png   f13c10d2-2692-457d-a208-8bb9e10b27dc
```